# How to change a colore of menu bar when user click on net link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want yo Change a color of nave when user click on other nav button i don't no how can i do this by code here is a image below:
[image]

when user click in abut then that color should be change in orange and home page active orange color will be black and about will be orange. i want to do this by JavaScript. here is a code lines below.

```
<div class="container clearfix">
          <nav id="menu" class="navigation" 
           role="navigation" style="float: left">
          <a href="#">Show navigation</a>
          <ul id="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="TP.aspx">T-P</a></li>
            <li><a href="MP.aspx">M-P</a></li>
            <li><a href="BM.aspx">B-M</a></li>
            <li><a href="RB.aspx">R-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="LC.aspx">L-C</a></li>
          </ul>         
         </nav>
  </div>
```

i use this JavaScript for change this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
 jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var make_button_active = function()
{
  //Get item siblings
  var siblings =($(this).siblings());
  //Remove active class on all buttons
  siblings.each(function (index)
    {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }  )
  //Add the clicked button class
  $(this).addClass('active');}
  //Attach events to menu
  $(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $(".menu li").click(make_button_active);
  }  )
</script>
```

but nothing happen please let me know how can i do this. anyone have any Idea?

Thank You

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1472219.aspx/1

Comment: In css you should have active class defined: `.active{background-color:#F18E40;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi more simple way to chafe class in li

```
string thisURL = this.Page.GetType().Name.ToString();       
        switch (thisURL)
        {
            case "home_aspx":
                lihome.Attributes.Add("class", "Active");                
                break;
         case "support_aspx":
                lisupport.Attributes.Add("class", "Active");
                break;
         case "logout_aspx":
                lilogout.Attributes.Add("class", "Active");
                break;
         }
```

need to do this code on load event of page and it will working that vote for this solution=)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here. For one menu is the value of an id so you would need to reference it in jquery with $('#menu"). Below is a working version of your code. I had to remove the href attributes to achieve the desired style change with minimal effort. You now have two choices:

1. Use this code and swap content dynamically using javascript and css display property
2. On each page in your site modify the markup, to set the active nav item; with this approach the javascript is not necessary.

   ```
   <htmL>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var make_button_active = function(){
        //Get item siblings
        var siblings =($(this).siblings());
        //Remove active class on all buttons
        siblings.each(function (index){
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        //Add the clicked button class
       $(this).addClass('active');
      }
      //Attach events to menu
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("li").click(make_button_active);
      });

   </script>
   <style>
     .active{
     background-color: red;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="container clearfix">
     <nav id="menu" class="navigation" 
      role="navigation" style="float: left">
     <a href="#">Show navigation</a>
     <ul id="nav">
       <li class="active"><a>Home</a></li>
       <li><a >About</a></li>
       <li><a >T-P</a></li>
       <li><a >M-P</a></li>
       <li><a >B-M</a></li>
       <li><a >R-B</a></li>
       <li><a >L-C</a></li>
     </ul>         
    </nav>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```